# Installing a third party firewall

Tags: firewall, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the Windows XP firewall good enough?](https://superuser.com/questions/17504/is-the-windows-xp-firewall-good-enough)

Should you worry about using third party firewall or the windows firewall is sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On XP the firewall only monitors **incoming** connections. If a Trojan gets past your anti-virus then you have no way of knowing if it's "calling home".

Installing a 3<sup>rd</sup> party firewall like [Comodo](http://www.comodo.com) will allow you to monitor **outgoing** connections as well and is a back up in case something does get past your anti-virus.

Don't forget to disable the Windows one as they might not play nice together.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a third party firewall just because you have previous experience with a similar firewall on other OS. For example, people with FreeBSD background find [wipfw](http://wipfw.sourceforge.net/) very handy.